# A measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, functional-analysis

Suppose $f\geq 0$ be a measurable function such that

$$\int_Bf\leq \frac{m(B)}{1+m(B)}$$ for any ball.

Then show that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(kx)g(x)\to 0$$

as $k\to \infty$ for any $g$ integrable in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_B f(x)\ dx \le \frac{m(B)}{1+m(B)}$?

Comment: yeah, I corrected.

Comment: Sorry, f is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, but I'm not sure if we can obtain a proof just from that.

Anyway, let us first note that if we prove the assertion for $g\geq0$ we are done, since
$$
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(kx)g(x)\,dm\right|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(kx)|g(x)|\,dm.
$$

The hypothesis on $f$ implies that $f$ is integrable and $\int f\,dm\leq1$. Indeed, let $B_n$ be the ball of radius $n$ centered at the origin. Then, by Monotone Convergence, $$
\int f\,dm=\lim_n\int f\; 1_{B_n}\,dm=\lim_n\int_{B_n} f\,dm\leq 1.
$$

Knowing that $f$ is integrable, almost every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a  Lebesgue point, so  $f\leq1$ a.e. by the inequality
$$
\frac1{m(B)}\int_Bf\,dm\leq\frac1{1+m(B)}.
$$

The integrability of $g$ implies that 
$$
\lim_{K\to\infty}\int_{g>K}g=0.
$$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $K$ such that $\int_{g>K}g\,dm<\varepsilon$. Then, writing $g_K$ for the function $g\;1_{g\leq K}$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int f(kx)g(x)\,dm&=&\int_{g\leq K}f(kx)g(x)\,dm +\int_{g>K}f(kx)g(x)\,dm\\
&\leq&\int f(kx)g_K(x)\,dm +\varepsilon\\
&=&\frac1{k^n}\int f(t) g_K(t/k)\,dm+\varepsilon\\
&\leq&\frac{K}{k^n}+\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty}\int f(kx)g(x)\,dm\leq\varepsilon.
$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that the $\limsup$ is zero, and so the limit exists and is zero:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int f(kx)g(x)\,dm=0.
$$

*(thanks to Norbert and to Nick Strehlke for the ideas to shorten the proof)*

Comment: This solution seems to me too complicated. Once you have proved that $\Vert f\Vert_\infty\leq 1$. You can note that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(kx)g(x)d\mu(x)=k^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(t)g(t/k)d\mu(t)$$ And apply dominated convergence theorem to the last integral to get $0$. Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: I think you are right. My proof just came that way as I started thinking about the problem, and it took me a while to notice that the hypothesis implies $\|f\|_\infty\leq1$, so by the time I was in position to notice your observation, I was already involved in the more complicated proof. Actually, I usually make an effort to try an avoid "simple functions' proofs", but I didn't immediately see the way here.

Comment: So, why don't you edit your solution to shorter one?

Comment: I started doing it, but then I noticed that is not obvious to me how to apply dominated convergence to your integral; what would the dominating function be?

Comment: I Little hard but there is a pretty nice answer! I will check the details. But I believe it is a correct answer.

Comment: Here's one way to use Norbert's observation to shorten the proof (though it doesn't use dominated convergence). Assuming $|g|$ is bounded by $M$, the integral that Norbert wrote down is no bigger than $k^{-n}M\|f\|_{L^1} \leq k^{-n} M$. That gives the result for bounded functions. In general, choose $g_\epsilon$ bounded with $\|g - g_\epsilon\|_{L^1} < \epsilon$, bound the integral of $f(kx)$ against $g(x)$ by $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\|g-g_\epsilon\|_{L^1} + \int f(kx)g_\epsilon(x)\,dx$, and use $\|f\|_{L^\infty} \leq 1$.